# How to find the duplicate line from csv file

Tags: java

I have a CSV file with 5 columns. I need to find all duplicates from the file.

From the below code, I can find all empty rows. Similarly, I need to find all duplicate values from the file. How can I find them?

Validation on employee id and cost center need to find all duplicates based on those two values.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(_config.getPayrollFileUpload().getFile().getInputStream()));
while ((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
   currentLine = removeCommaFromData(currentLine);
   currentLineSplit = currentLine.replace(",", "");
   currentLineNum++;
   if (!currentLineSplit.equals("") && currentLineNum != 1) {
   } else {
      if (currentLineNum != 1) {
         _messages.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage("error.payroll.emptyRow", String.valueOf(currentLineNum)));
         emptyRow = true;
      }
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use a Set or HashMap to find the duplicates.

Comment: Simplest solution would be to create a Set that holds row values or hash, to check if there are any duplicates. You could also go with JDK8 Files.lines(...).distinct().forEach(...). But it depends how large is Your row key - the values that matter in finding duplicates.

Comment: @Beri `distinct()` is the *opposite* of what's needed